# manage response of push notification in php

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

**it's my notification comman function**

```
   public function notification($token,$title,$body){

           $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

            //$token = "clyEl";
            $serverKey = 'AAAAG';
            //$title = "Title";
            //$body = "Body of the message";
            $notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body, 'sound' => 'enable', 'badge' => '1');
            $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
            $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
            $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            //Send the request
            $result=curl_exec($ch);

    }
```

**this code call in to other function **

```
 $send_notification=$this->notification($token,$title,$body);
    return response()->json(['status'=>true,'message'=>'request send successfully']);
```

**but in json response i get response like this**

```
{"multicast_id":6583845632900792550,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1518436953401414"}]}{"status":true,"message":"request send successfully"}
```

**i just need only like this**

```
{"status":true,"message":"request send successfully"}
```

Comment: The thing is, its third party api url. so you can not control the response until and unless you have the control of changing the code of response. So u can update the response from your side on the bases of the response you get. Say for example, you get `success:1` in initial response then based on that, you can put `if` condition and can update based on your needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: can u help me for this result

{"status":true,"message":"request send successfully"}

plz...

Comment: This is asking for the help of another question. Play around with your logic and response and come up with new question if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show only

```
{"status":true,"message":"request send successfully"}
```

then write

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

in your code.

It solves your issue